# MySQL Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with a MySQL join query - unfortunately I am not too good with joins.

```
Table page_section:
-------------------
id
page_id
name
display_order


Table page_section_sub:
-----------------------
id
page_section_id
page_id
content
```

One `page_section` can have many `page_section_sub`

On my page I want to display rows from `page_section_sub` ordered by `page_section.display_order`

Currently I have this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM page_section_sub WHERE page_section_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
ORDER BY display_order";
```

But this is not working as it is missing the join. How do I do this?

Comment: something like that: `select pss.* from page_section_sub pss join page_section ps on pss.page_section_id = ps.id where ps.id between 1 and 5 order by ps.display_order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select pss.*
from page_section_sub pss
inner join page_section ps on pss.page_section_id = ps.id
where pss.page_section_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
order by ps.display_order
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT * FROM page_section
LEFT JOIN page_section_sub ON page_section.page_id = page_section_sub.page_id
WHERE page_section_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) 
ORDER BY display_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select page_section_id.* from page_section_id natural join page_section 
WHERE page_section_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) order by page_section_id.display_order
```