# Number of rows on the basis of Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables class_tbl (id,class_name) and  student_tbl(id,class_id,student_name).

I want to display all class in a table format and want to show number of students  in each class.

How to do this in one mysql query?

Comment: Search for mysql join 2 tables.

Comment: Your student table design implies that a student can take only one class. Is that what you really want?

Comment: No, in my case, one student can take many class and ofcourse one class have many students, so in these two tables there is many-to-many relationship, I just want to run a query that give me the list of all classes name and number of students belong to each class. But I want to do this by one query, how I will do this? I need a query for this along with little explaination. thanks Honeyboy Wilson

Comment: You need a linking table to establish that many-to-many relationship. Class_id does not belong in the students table. You need a studentsclasses table with a class_id and a student_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:
`SELECT class_name, count(student_tbl.id) as number_of_students FROM class_tbl c INNER JOIN student_tbl s ON c.id=s.class_id GROUP BY class_id`;

Comment: Thankkkkk you so much vpalade. You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided very little information in your question. Please take some time to read some of the question on stackoverflow which are closed / answered / up-voted and spend some time thinking about why they have merited such action.

Assuming that your "student_tbl" actually decomposes the N:M relationship between students and classes (otherwise, as Honeyboy Wilson says, it is impossible to resolve the query) all you need is a [count of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346345/mysql-count-occurrences-of-distinct-values) in the table grouped by class_id. If you want to add the name of the class then its [just a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746917/mysql-join-query). This is remedial level SQL and already covered in other answers.